# Permissions issues with F# and Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, reflection, f#

I have a portable F# library targeting Silverlight 5 and .Net 4.5 (profile 47 to be specific). I'm attempting to use `FSharpType` and `FSharpValue` from `Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection` to handle some serialization of union and record types from another portable library, although this one is in C# and targeting the same portable profile. However, accessing these APIs from within my Silverlight app gives me a `MethodAccessException`, the top of whose call stack is below. I'm trying to determine if it's even possible to access these F# reflection APIs from a Silverlight 5.0 app.

```
System.MethodAccessException occurred
  HResult=-2146233072
  Message=Attempt to access method Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilationMappingAttribute..ctor(Microsoft.FSharp.Core.SourceConstructFlags) in violation of security transparency rules failed.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.CheckLinktimeDemands(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, RuntimeModule module, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
       at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
       at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
       at System.RuntimeType.GetCustomAttributes(Boolean inherit)
```

(Edit) I'm using elements from `Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection` and passing `BindingFlags.Public`; so there isn't any attempt at things that ought to be restricted, like accessing private members.

Comment: This kinda makes sense: using reflection one can work around access rules (e.g. call private methods), so it's logical that reflection is out of bounds.

Comment: If I were attempting to access private members; e.g. that would make sense. However, the portions of the API I'm using are all using `BindingFlags.Public`.